# Copy role resources to other role programatically

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, user-roles, duplicate

As title says i want copy role resources from one to other.

For example:

I give one of my role id which is dynamically and then i get all resouces for that role id and assign that resources to other roles.

Comment: Need to create new rule programtically  and this rule assign to give use id?

Comment: Pls explain more details

Comment: I want to copy role resources of any role id to other role id.

Answer (score 4):

Here we go:

```
function copyResources($sourceRoleId, $destinationRoleId) {
    // Delete old resources for destination role
    Mage::getResourceModel('admin/rules_collection')
        ->addFieldToFilter('role_id', $destinationRoleId)
        ->walk('delete');

    // Copy resources
    $resources = Mage::getResourceModel('admin/rules_collection')
        ->addFieldToFilter('role_id', $sourceRoleId);

    foreach ($resources as $resource) {
        $resource
            ->unsetData('rule_id')
            ->setData('role_id', $destinationRoleId)
            ->save();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a quick way to copy all of the permissions from one role to another, here is a quick Javascript snippet you can use in the console:

```js
// Execute the following in the console from the role resources tab you want to copy:

var elems = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
var checkedPerms = [];

for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    var isChecked = elems[i].checked;
    if(isChecked && elems[i].id) {
        checkedPerms.push(elems[i].id);
    }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(checkedPerms));

// Place the output of console.log into the var below and execute the following on the role resources tab you want to copy to:

var checkedPerms = ''; // Place the output of the above console.log into this var

checkedPerms = JSON.parse(checkedPerms);

for (var i = 0; i < checkedPerms.length; i++) {
    var el = document.getElementById(checkedPerms[i]);
    if (el) {
        el.checked = true;
    }
}
```